# Error Android Dex: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am getting the following error when compiling an Android project on Intelli J Idea:

```
Android Dex: [TodoTxtTouch] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Android Dex: [TodoTxtTouch] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
Android Dex: [TodoTxtTouch] at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
Android Dex: [TodoTxtTouch] at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:128)
Android Dex: [TodoTxtTouch] at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:145)
Android Dex: [TodoTxtTouch] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:206)
```

Anyone knows what might cause these or how can I put the DX compiler into debug mode using intellij so I can discover what file is causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you added duplicated package in your project, You can try to remove android-support-v13.jar and android-support-v4.jar?